# Unable to publish an action

Tags: facebook, object, action, publish

I'm attempting to create a Facebook Open Graph App similar to the Washington Post Social Reader, which will announce in a person's news feed when they read an article on my website, www.zeitlife.co.uk.

I have followed the Open Graph tutorial closely, identifying an action and an object, and creating several sample ones to test aggregation. I've created a button saying "Add to Timeline" , but I've been unable to publish an action (in this case "read") and receive an ID for the action.

One issue I encountered was the debugger tool telling me my Open Graph meta tags lay outside my  tags, which aren't visible in a self-hosted wordpress site. However, I installed Meta SEO Pack plugin which allowed me to place the Open Graph meta tags in a post's meta description, and the debugger tool accepted this.

This raised the complication of which part of the full Open Graph code (action and object) to put in the meta description; I've tried placing the "head" part in the Meta description and the "body part in the main post body, which resulted in a non-functional button.

Perhaps you could take a look at the code I've used and see if there are any problems?

**Code in Meta Description:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# zeitlife: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/zeitlife#">
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="308222752522151" /> 
<meta property="og:type"        content="zeitlife:article" /> 
<meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould" /> 
<meta property="og:title"       content="Cabana: Brazilian that Breaks the Mould" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Restaurant Review" /> 
<meta property="og:image"       content="http://www.zeitlife.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/IMG_2435.jpg" />

</head> 
</html>
```

**Code in main body of post:**

```
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript"> function read()
{FB.api('/me/zeitlife:article' + '?article=zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould &access_token=AAAEYU7OsZC6cBAG0oRKggspR5xjr17Nlpntj2ylxOuN6o3Tztry2EKPWq3JO97yG9De1tlN1SEpqKarovmZAlNKLsEM3BdR4AZAIV6ARDEkQsVSMK3C','post',
function(response) {
var msg = 'Error occured';
if (!response || response.error) {
if (response.error) {
msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
}
alert(msg);
} 
else {
alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
}
});
}
    </script>

    <body> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
FB.init({ 
appId:'308222752522151', cookie:true, 
status:true, xfbml:true, oauth:true
});
    </script>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="Post To Your Timeline " onclick="read()" />
    </form>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Thank you very much for you help in advance, it's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you could have created a WordPress plugin to modify the head HTML code, e.g. hook into the wp_head function using hooks.

Secondly, it looks like you have a created a custom read action. Facebook will reject this when you try to get it approved. You should use the built in read action to make the approval process easier.

Finally, the JS function to make the read call is incorrect. The code is ok, but the data you pass into the call is wrong. You don't need to use the access token in the function and you must use the full URL to the article (i.e. include http(s)).

Change your code to something like this:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //  publish action to facebook
            FB.api( '/me/zeitlife:read', 'post', { article : 'http://zeitlife.co.uk/cabana-brazilian-food-that-breaks-the-mould/' } );
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
    });
}, 2000 );
```

Notice that the action is 'zeitlife:read' and not 'zeitlife:article' as your done in your code. Article is a parameter in the call. You should test your API calls using the API Explorer tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/